# read python STDOUT realtime

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

My code is as follows, basically this module will run the required command and capture its ouput line by line but in my case when the command runs, it takes just more than a second to return to the command prompt and thats where child.stdout.read(1) hangs, if I run a normal command using this it prints everthing as expected. but in a particular case where, the command prints somthing to STDOUT and then takes some time to return to the prompt, it hangs.. Please help

New code:

```
def run_command(shell_command):
'''run the required command and print the log'''
child = subprocess.Popen(shell_command, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = child.communicate()
print stdoutdata

print "Exiting.."
```

Error:

```
  File "upgrade_cloud.py", line 62, in <module>
stop_cloud()
File "upgrade_cloud.py", line 49, in stop_cloud
run_command(shell_command)
 File "upgrade_cloud.py", line 33, in run_command
 (stdoutdata, stderrdata) = child.communicate()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 693, in communicate
stdout = self.stdout.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Hm... I suspect this may be [issue 7213](http://bugs.python.org/issue7213).  Do you have multiple Popen instances running at the same time?

Comment: No, at a time it just runs a single command and comes out.

Comment: Please help, I am stuck on this issue

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the actual command itself is hanging.  If that's the case, there's little Python can do.

Comment: No, thats not the case, I am able to run the command manually

Comment: Does the command prompt for input? To debug, you could temporarily remove `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and see what's printed to the screen.

Comment: related: [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279)

Comment: *"I am able to run the command manually"*. What happens if you copy-paste the command into `subprocess.check_call(shell_command, shell=True)` (without redirecting)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
child.wait()
```

This line causes Python to wait for the child process to exit.  If the child process tries to print a lot of data to stdout, it will block waiting for Python to read said data.  Since Python is waiting for the child process and the child process is waiting for Python, you get a deadlock.

I would recommend using [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `subprocess.Popen`.  You could also use the [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method instead of the `.wait()` method.

Comment: Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Feb 27 2014, 19:43:51)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 Version is 2.6, it does not have check_output and the thing is i cant upgrade the environment to latest python

Comment: It still hangs,   File "upgrade_cloud.py", line 14, in run_command
    child.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 693, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
KeyboardInterrupt .. I had to use the keyboard interrupt

Comment: Once you've done a `communicate()`, `child.stdout` is a useless object.  You need to save the return value from `communicate()` and work with that.

Comment: `child = subprocess.Popen(shell_command, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 (stdoutdata, stderrdata) = child.communicate()
 print stdoutdata`
So ideally this should print all the lines of the stdoutput, right?, but it is not able to do so

Comment: Communicate is definitely the way to go. Reading one character at a time is highly inefficient.

Comment: With the code, in my latest above comment, ideally i should be able to print the data, but i am not able to, however for the commands that doesnt wait, it works fine

Comment: @rohit: Please post the full error you are getting in the question so we can look at it.